# NoneType object is not callable when importing sknetwork in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, spyder

When i try to run `import sknetwork` as a single line python file, I get different results depending on the editor I use to run it. See https://scikit-network.readthedocs.io/en/latest/# for more information on sknetwork.

#### Behaviour in Visual Studio Code

When trying to run `import sknetwork` as a single line python file in Visual Studio Code, i get a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\****\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\****\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\****\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\****\.spyder-py3\test_sknetwork.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sknetwork.data import house
  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sknetwork\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sknetwork.topology
  File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sknetwork\topology\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sknetwork.topology.kcliques import Cliques
  File "sknetwork\topology\kcliques.pyx", line 11, in init sknetwork.topology.kcliques
  File "sknetwork\topology\kcliques.pyx", line 11, in __Pyx_PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_kcliques(void)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\****\.spyder-py3>
```

#### Behaviour in Spyder

Running the same code, even the same file, in Spyder works just fine.

#### Behaviour when runing from command line

Running the same code, even the same file, from the command line works just fine.

My conda environment has the following packages installed:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py38_0
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda-client           1.9.0            py38haa95532_0
anaconda-navigator        2.1.0            py38haa95532_0
anyio                     2.2.0            py38haa95532_2
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h2bbff1b_1
arrow                     0.13.1                   py38_0
astroid                   2.6.6            py38haa95532_0
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
autopep8                  1.5.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports                 1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_2
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
bcrypt                    3.2.0            py38he774522_0
beautifulsoup4            4.10.0             pyh06a4308_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
black                     19.10b0                    py_0
bleach                    4.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2021.10.26           haa95532_2
certifi                   2021.10.8        py38haa95532_0
cffi                      1.15.0           py38h2bbff1b_0
chardet                   4.0.0           py38haa95532_1003
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py38_1
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda                     4.11.0           py38haa95532_0
conda-build               3.21.4           py38haa95532_0
conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py38h8cc25b3_1
conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
cookiecutter              1.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography              3.4.8            py38h71e12ea_0
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0    anaconda
debugpy                   1.5.1            py38hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
docutils                  0.17.1           py38haa95532_1
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0
filelock                  3.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
flake8                    3.9.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
future                    0.18.2                   py38_1
git                       2.32.0               haa95532_1
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize                 1.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        4.8.2            py38haa95532_0
importlib_metadata        4.8.2                hd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1            py38haa95532_0
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py38haa95532_1
ipython                   7.29.0           py38hd4e2768_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi                      0.17.2           py38haa95532_1
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
joblib                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9d                   h2bbff1b_0
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
jupyter_client            7.0.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.9.1            py38haa95532_0
jupyter_server            1.4.1            py38haa95532_0
jupyterlab                3.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
keyring                   23.4.0           py38haa95532_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
libarchive                3.4.2                h5e25573_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.10.1               ha925a31_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0
libwebp                   1.2.0                h2bbff1b_0
libxml2                   2.9.12               h0ad7f3c_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38he774522_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py38_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py38he774522_1
mistune                   0.8.4           py38he774522_1000
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
mypy_extensions           0.4.3                    py38_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py38_0
nbclassic                 0.2.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py38haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
notebook                  6.4.6            py38haa95532_0
numpy                     1.21.4                   pypi_0    pypi
numpydoc                  1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl                   1.1.1l               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py38haa95532_1
paramiko                  2.7.2                      py_0
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
pathspec                  0.7.0                      py_0
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.4.0            py38hd45dc43_0
pip                       21.2.2           py38haa95532_0
pkginfo                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
pluggy                    1.0.0            py38haa95532_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prometheus_client         0.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
psutil                    5.8.0            py38h2bbff1b_1
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
py-lief                   0.10.1           py38ha925a31_0
pycodestyle               2.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyflakes                  2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py38haa95532_0
pylint                    2.9.6            py38haa95532_1
pyls-black                0.4.6                hd3eb1b0_0
pyls-spyder               0.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pynacl                    1.4.0            py38h62dcd97_1
pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38ha925a31_4
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py38h196d8e1_0
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.8                hdbf39b2_5
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-jsonrpc-server     0.4.0                      py_0
python-language-server    0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywin32                   228              py38hbaba5e8_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py38_1000
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py38_0
pyyaml                    6.0              py38h2bbff1b_1
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py38hd77b12b_2
qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer                 0.1.10             pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      1.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
regex                     2021.8.3         py38h2bbff1b_0
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rope                      0.21.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rtree                     0.9.7            py38h2eaa2aa_1
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py38h2bbff1b_0
scikit-learn              1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-network            0.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                58.0.4           py38haa95532_0
sip                       4.19.13          py38ha925a31_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38haa95532_1
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx                    4.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    5.0.5            py38haa95532_2
spyder-kernels            2.0.5            py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0
terminado                 0.9.4            py38haa95532_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
text-unidecode            1.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl             3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tinycss                   0.4             pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tk                        8.6.11               h2bbff1b_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.1              py38h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.62.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
typed-ast                 1.4.3            py38h2bbff1b_1
typing_extensions         3.10.0.2           pyh06a4308_0
ujson                     4.0.2            py38hd77b12b_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.26.7             pyhd3eb1b0_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
watchdog                  2.1.6            py38haa95532_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
whichcraft                0.6.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2              py38haa95532_2
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38he774522_1
xmltodict                 0.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in the VSCode Python extension. You should report it there.

Comment: same with pycharm

Comment: Same in my VS code on both Windows and Ubuntu. But it works on VS code's jupyter notebook environment.